# iCloud Drive stuck on "Waiting to upload"

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

On both iOS and MacOS, documents in iCloud Drive are never uploaded. Text underneath each document just says "Waiting to Upload"

Already tried turning iCloud Drive off and on again

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Same issue for me lately. Nothing seems to help: rebooting, connecting to Wifi, waiting for Photos app to finish its upload, waiting several days, sharing file using "Add People" from Files app (which then shows "Uploading..." but never finishes). Called Apple Support and they suggested to wipe the device and re-install from backup. I'm worried that this wipes all the pending changes.

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak for macOS, however iOS (iPhone, iPad) iCloud synchronization will be either very slow or just stuck when on a cellular connection. Connect your iOS device to a WiFi and it should sync up almost instantly. This is what resolved my issue with Numbers documents not syncing up on iPhone 6s with iOS 12.1.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had a similar issue and since my file was a pdf downloaded from a webpage I thought that this could be the issue. Having deleted the kMDItemWhereFroms extended attribute the file synced in seconds:

```
xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms my_file_name.pdf
```